# Cannot move autonomously on slopes

Tags: navigation, ros

Use a 2d map
The robot normally runs on a flat road.
However, when the robot tries to run on a slope, it tilts. Then it recognizes the ground as an obstacle and cannot make the path.
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You should be using the tf package to solve this. Also sloped terrain is 3D, so you can’t capture that *nicely* with a 2D map. Collision detection should be done in the Odom frame.

Comment: Thank you very much.
But I am a beginner and don't know how to do it.
Do you have any articles that can help me?

Comment: I use ros noetic .

Comment: It depends on what sensor you’re using to create the map, but [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) might be a good starting place.